# Another time: mootools vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, mootools

I've just finished to translate (in Italian...for Italian developers that are too lazy to learn English :D ) this great article (by Aaron Newton) about the topic the title refers to:

http://jqueryvsmootools.com/

While I was doing it, I had the opportunity to focus and to deeply understand the main goals about these two fantastic javascript frameworks.

Leaving out all the details about how each framework work etc etc, I have to tell that I really prefer Mootools (I love its "verbosity" and its way to extend native JS).

I'm kinda new here in the stackoverflow community, and I noticed how much jQuery "questions cloud" is really bigger than Mootools one. So, I don't know if it's just about the popularity or about the fact that people really prefer jQuery instead of Mootools.

Going to the question, I'd like to ask (and I think it's a very good topic to confront each other), if you are experienced with both of them:

Why do you prefer jQ rather than moo, or why do you think jQ is more powerful than moo?

Thanks!

Comment: You should totally drop asking such subjective answers and use jQUery instead. PS: This will likely get closed / moved.

Comment: Why are you saying that? It would be great if you can explain the part "and use jQuery instead" ;) . It's just about that I don't know technically WHY so many people prefer jQuery!

Comment: @steweb: jQuery has got a huge community and a plugin for literally anything exists, so people don't have to use their brains so much. That's probably an important point </sarcasm>

Comment: http://mootools.net/slickspeed/ mootools say that jquery selector is faster as of now in chrome :)

Comment: @jAndy thanks! :) well, it could be a very important point... But, I know that making a mootools plugin is as easy as making a jQuery one. Also, use and include a plugin from both frameworks I think it doesn't require any particular knowledge. The point is: why do you start develop (and then you produce "public" plugins) in jQuery rather than Mootools? (I know, it's kinda weird :D .. however, I think this can help a lot me and JS developers in general)

Comment: @steweb That's a meme here on SO, don't have the link handy right now gonna post it later :)

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel ..thanks :) and sorry about this "forum" question :)